# How do I select and match from multiple tables?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

This is my table layout:

```
-- Table structure for table `areas`
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `areas` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- Table structure for table `matches`
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `matches` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `view_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('h','n') NOT NULL,
  `exp_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- Table structure for table `users`
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `limit_age` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '18:30',
  `limit_gender` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notifications` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `image_big` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `image_small` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `crop_data` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `registered_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `views` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hots` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

I will try to explain this better:

I have a given `ID`.
I would like to select one entry from `users` which is not the `ID` i have given
AND which `user_id` does not exist in `matches`
AND has `visible` = 1
AND where any `country` + `city` matches the given users `country` + `city`

Is this the correct way to do it (12 is an example of an given ID):

```
SELECT *
FROM users a
INNER JOIN areas ON areas.user_id = a.id
WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM matches)
AND NOT a.id = '12'
AND a.limit_age = '18:30'
AND a.visible = '1'
AND areas.country = 'sverige'
AND areas.city = 'gbg'
```

Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: I formatted it to make it easier to read, but still don't quite understand what you are trying. What kind of field is limit_age? Why don't you compare visible to something? What do you mean by "first entry"? You say you want to match on country and city, but you compare to age and gender and visible. Which is the "one requested?" What are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry forgot to type visible = 1 and limit_age is a just a VARCHAR field. It's the part on country and city where i got stuck. Not sure how to match that because every user can have multiple areas added to them a:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll make an attempt at this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users a
INNER JOIN areas ON areas.user_id = a.id
WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM matches)
AND a.visible = '1'
AND a.limit_age = '18:30'
AND a.limit_gender = 'f'
AND areas.country = ?
AND areas.city = ?;
```

This is SELECTing from "users", and returning a result only if that user also has an entry in the "areas" table.  The first item in the WHERE clause ensures that a row will not be returned if the users.id (a.id) is found in the user_id field on the "matches" table.  Next, I added checks for visible = 1, limit_age, and limit_gender as specified in his attempt.  Finally, I left country and city parameterized so that they can be added as parameters in the php code.  If anything that should give you a starting point.

Comment: hi, check my edit :) explains better i think, tried your code aswell